# What should be the return type of async method returning nothing

Tags: c#, async-await

I have the piece of code below which is giving analyzer warning:

```
    public async Task SendPasswordEmail(string emailId, string link)
    {
        await _emailSender
            .To(emailId)
            .Subject(EmailUtilsConstants.PasswordEmailSubject)
            .Body(EmailUtilsConstants.PasswordEmailText + link)
            .SendAsync();
    }
```

The warning I get is:

> The method 'SendPasswordEmail' do not need to use async/await.

If the method should not use async await, what should be the return type? `Task`. So is below fix to analyser correct?

```
    public Task SendPasswordEmail(string emailId, string link)
    {
        _emailSender
            .To(emailId)
            .Subject(EmailUtilsConstants.PasswordEmailSubject)
            .Body(EmailUtilsConstants.PasswordEmailText + link)
            .SendAsync();
        return Task.Completed;
    }
```

Comment: `public async Task` sais it expects a Task. Async/await is nothing else then returning a Task with a value inside the compiler will unpack when for example Task<int> is used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can remove `async` and `await` keywords in case of single line inside function. 
I guess `SendAsync` returns `Task` object already, so not need to await, just return that `Task`:

```
public Task SendPasswordEmail(string emailId, string link)
{
    return _emailSender
        .To(emailId)
        .Subject(EmailUtilsConstants.PasswordEmailSubject)
        .Body(EmailUtilsConstants.PasswordEmailText + link)
        .SendAsync();
}
```

`Async/Await` will introduce additional overhead to your method. Compiler will create "state machine" for all async methods which is unnecessary in case of single line of code inside method body.

Update: (thanks for comment to @JohnathanBarclay)

Another difference in case of eliding `async/await`m the exception handling will change a bit. The state machine for `async` methods will capture exceptions from your code and place them on the returned task. But, it won't be case in case of eliding `async/await`.

Read https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html for more.

Comment: True, the only issue would be if `To`, `Subject` or `Body` threw an exception; it would be thrown directly rather than being placed on the `Task`. It isn't just a simple pass-through to `SendAsync` so I think the warning is slightly naive.